# Xcode 10.3 does not work on MacOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (non beta)

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode10, macos-big-sur

I have tried to format my MacOS, redownload Xcode 10.3. It just doesnt work.
[image]

```
Logs:

Process:               Xcode [22467]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Downloads/Xcode_10.3.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               10.3 (14492.2)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-14492002000000000~2 (10G8)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [22467]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Users/USER/Downloads/Xcode_10.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib
PlugIn Identifier:       libMainThreadChecker.dylib
PlugIn Version:          ??? (64492.1)

Date/Time:             2020-11-13 16:52:33.909 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y908)
Anonymous UUID:        46BBB97A-6E02-4B36-B8CE-640575A752F0


Time Awake Since Boot: 4500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007fff2379c9b9
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Bus error: 10
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process:   exc handler [22467]

VM Regions Near 0x7fff2379c9b9:
    __TEXT                   7fff22c03000-7fff23600000 [ 10.0M] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
--> __TEXT                   7fff23600000-7fff23800000 [ 2048K] r-x/rwx SM=PRV  /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    Submap                   7fff23800000-7fff40000000 [456.0M] r--/rwx SM=PRV  process-only VM submap

Application Specific Information:
/Users/junjie/Downloads/Xcode_10.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib
ProductBuildVersion: 10G8

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libMainThreadChecker.dylib      0x00000001176b8069 swizzleImplementationFast + 115
1   libMainThreadChecker.dylib      0x00000001176b7ef0 addSwizzler + 165
2   libMainThreadChecker.dylib      0x00000001176b7aec __library_initializer + 2937
3   dyld                            0x0000000117b21df5 ImageLoaderMachO::doImageInit(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 321
4   dyld                            0x0000000117b2246d ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) +
```

Any suggestion or idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you reload the command line tools after formatting ?

Comment: @dspr yes i did.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok I managed to get it up and running by deleting ~/Downloads/Xcode_10.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib
It compiles my project.

To be safe, I have copied this same dylib file from latest Xcode 12.2 and put into that folder. It is still working so far.

Comment: It works for `Command xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 10` and `Command xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool failed with exit code 10` too. Thank U!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, I initially solved it using `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTDisableMainThreadChecker 1`. After this, Xcode 10 seemed to work on macOS 11, and everything would build from within Xcode.

I then had the weirdest issue - when compiling from the command line using `xcodebuild`, the whole machine would grind to a halt and eventually hang, requiring a "hold down the power button" restart. The problem turned out to be that `ibtool` (used for compiling IB files) was not honouring `DVTDisableMainThreadChecker`, and was still crashing. This was somehow causing the machine to get into a state where it stopped responding.

The solution was to copy libMainThreadChecker.dylib from Xcode 12 into the Xcode 10 package. After that the problem went away.